# Javascript on page preventing Selenium from detecting certain frames & elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Python to fill in a form on a site where the frames are visible in the html but I still haven't been able to get Selenium to detect any frames or form elements.

I think it is because there is Javascript in the  since I see the same scripts referenced throughout the html of the form fields.

I'm very new to this so I'm not quite sure where to get started. From what I've read I might need to use Python's "execute_script" and/or Selenium's javascriptexecutor.

Here is a snippet of the HTML from top to the frame with the fields I'm after **(the frame name "main" is the one with the form in it):**

```html
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>eBridge Inc.</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startup() {
            parent.header.location.href = 'header.aspx?guid=' + window.name;
            parent.nav.location.href = 'nav.aspx?guid=' + window.name;
            parent.main.location.href = 'welcome.aspx?guid=' + window.name;
            parent.footer.location.href = 'footer.aspx?guid=' + window.name;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<frameset rows="75px,25px,*,30px" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" onload="startup();">
    <frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" marginheight="0">
    <frame name="nav" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" marginheight="0">
    <frame name="main" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0">
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Retrieve</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
                <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
                <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
                <link id="mainStylesheet" href="../StyleSheet.css?62" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link id="dhtmlxStylesheet" href="../Scripts/combobox/style/dhtmlxcombo_touch.css?62" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link id="datepickerStylesheet" href="../Scripts/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?62" rel="stylesheet">
                <link id="jqueryuiStylesheet" href="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css?62" rel="stylesheet">

                <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../Scripts/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../Scripts/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script src="../Scripts/combobox/scripts/dhtmlxcommon.js?version=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../Scripts/combobox/scripts/dhtmlxcombo_touch.js?version=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        try
                        {
                            parent.nav.document.location = '../nav.aspx?menu=&guid=' + parent.window.name;
                        }
                        catch(ex){}
                        //focus on first tb/ddl
                        $('#tblIndex').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').focus();

                        $("#start_date").datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true
                        });

                        $("#end_date").datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true
                        });

                        $("#start_date").mask("99/99/9999");
                        $("#end_date").mask("99/99/9999");

                        $("#start_calendar_icon").click(function (event) {
                            $("#start_date").focus();
                        });

                        $("#end_calendar_icon").click(function (event) {
                            $("#end_date").focus();
                        });
                        // for enter keystroke
                        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                            CheckKeyCode(e);
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        $('.dhx_combo_input').keyup(function (e) {
                            CheckKeyCode(e);
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
```

When I use the following python in Selenium, it throws the "no such frame" exception:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("header")
```

It does this for the rest of the frames as well.

So I tried listing all elements on the page using this:

```
for ii in ids:
    print(ii.get_attribute('id'))
```

And it only returns a few of the page elements (none of which are form fields), namely these:

```
stylesheet
hf
imgLogo
welcome
h_log_out
retrieve
aView
help
aSupport
cabnm
```

My goal is to input text into the form fields within the frame "main". I normally don't have any issue with using Python to interact with pages, but I'm not sure how to deal with the scripts on this page that seem to be preventing me from detecting and switching frames.

Any advice on whether the scripts are the culprit and if so, how to make them display the rest of the frames and elements is appreciated. I prefer solutions in Python but am open to anything.

Comment: By the ID names you are seeing, it looks like selenium is working in the "main" frame already. What happens if you call `driver.switch_to_default_content()` first, and then try switching?

Comment: I get no error from either "switch to default content" or when switching back to "main" afterward. Edit: I just fixed my code from by name to by id and was able to find tblIndex. Testing text input into fields now and will post results. I would like to know why I wasn't able to switch frames or locate any elements until I used your "switch to default" and then back again, though.

Comment: '@TodorMinakov: Thanks Todor, I was able to fill out and submit the form ONLY after adding the lines "driver.switch_to_default_content()" followed by "driver.switch_to.frame("main")". I tested it without both lines and it didn't work. I tested it without the second line (only switching to default content, not back to main) and it didn't work. Why did I have to switch to default content and then back to main before it was able to locate any frames?

Comment: Well as I said, all those element IDs sounded like selenium was in some of the frames already; how and why - I can't tell, it's probably something from your earlier code. Thus I suggested going back to the root first - a known location, and then switching;  glad it works for you now.

Comment: Yeah when that page loads if my first line of code is to switch to the header frame or the main frame or list all element id's, it still can't find any frames or form elements. Only when I switch to default can I switch into anything else. At least it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'@TodorMinakov: Thanks Todor, I was able to fill out and submit the form ONLY after adding the following lines before anything else:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("main")
```

I'd love to know why this is necessary, but at least it works now.

Thanks again Todor for your answer in the comments.